# jQuery mobile listviews split buttons, right button only

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, split-button

see this example http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/
Part: Split buttons

In that example, both the left and right part are buttons. 
How can I get that only the **right part** is button (the left is just a basic read-only text)?

Thanks!

Comment: in the example, every <li> is a wrapper for an <a> which contains all  elements of the row. Delete the a. Another thing you can do is use data-grids.

Comment: if I remove the <a>, the CSS is broken. not button style anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a working example made from the official split button example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nwg5b/

What you need to do is remove href="#" from a first a tag:

Change this:

```
<li><a href="#">
    <img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
    <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
    <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
</li>
```

to this:

```
<li><a>
    <img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
    <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
    <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
</li>
```

Finally you will need to dig inside jQuery Mobile css. Think about theme you want to use (theme c is used in the example). Open jQuery Mobile css and search for this class: **.ui-btn-up-c** where c is theme c (for example if theme a is used then search for **.ui-btn-up-a**).

Copy its content and put important at the end of every line. At the end of this new css block add this line:

```
cursor: default !important;
```

and name it as you want (In example case it is: readonly-state-c). It should all look like this:

```
.readonly-state-c {
    background: #eee !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    color: #2F3E46 !important;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{c-bup-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{c-bup-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{c-bup-shadow-radius}*/ #ffffff /*{c-bup-shadow-color}*/ !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/), to( #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/)) !important; /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/) !important; /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/) !important; /* FF3.6 */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/) !important; /* IE10 */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/) !important; /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient( #ffffff /*{c-bup-background-start}*/, #f1f1f1 /*{c-bup-background-end}*/) !important;   
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

Create new class from it and put it inside first a tag, like this:

```
<li><a class="readonly-state-c">
    <img src="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
    <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
    <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
    <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
</li>
```

And that is that.

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.

Comment: the fact that this is so hard to do is why I loathe when I have to work with jquery mobile. Thanks for the workaround though!