# jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 split button, right button only CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, customization

I tried creating a listview with listitems that have a button on the right side. Just like a jQuery Mobile split button listview, but only the right button should be clickable.
The left part should contain a label together with a text input.

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292521/2026623

But the class used in this answer was removed/renamed in jQuery mobile 1.4.0.
I found out that some of the properties are now in .ui-btn-a but not all.

So I tried implementing it myself (having little knowledge of CSS). This is what it looks so far:

HTML:

```
<li class="readonly-li-a">
    <a class="readonly-btn-a ui-field-contain">
        <label for="boss">Boss:</label>
        <input type="text" id="boss" name="boss">
    </a>
    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.readonly-btn-a {
    background: #fff!important /*{a-bup-background-color}*/;
    color: #333!important /*{a-bup-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bup-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-bup-shadow-color}*/;
    cursor: default !important; /* don't change to hand cursor */
    border: none !important;
}

.readonly-li-a {
    border: 0 solid #ddd !important;
    border-top-width: 1px !important; /*the line above the li */
    padding: .7em 1em !important; /*copied from .ui-li-static */
    background: #fff!important; /*white background instead of grey*/
    margin: 0 1px!important; /*the li stands out by 1px left/right without this*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/      rgba(0,0,0,.15) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/         rgba(0,0,0,.15) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px /*{global-box-shadow-size}*/              rgba(0,0,0,.15) /*{global-box-shadow-color}*/;
}
```

And this is what it looks in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/MasterQuestMaster/QJ9m2/

There are 2 problems with this solution and I hope someone can help me solving them.

- If you enter the text field, the blue shine gets cut off by the
  border of the -Tag. I think this is because of the padding I added
  to .readonly-li-a.
- The text input is not aligned correctly (the
  label is though)

Or maybe somebody even has tried this before me and found a better solution. If so, please post it.

Comment: for the split-btn remove all `data-` and replace them with classes, `<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars"></a>`. for the rest of issues, you have to play around until you get what you want http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4MYES/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a slight change in markup, I believe you can do this with 2 CSS rules. The existing ui-li-static and ui-body-inherit classes take care of the LI, so you only need a margin rule to line up the inputs and a class for the readonly-btn-a:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label>Normal:</label>
            <input type="text" id="normal" name="normal"/>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">
        <a href="#" class="readonly-btn-a" >
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <label>Link:</label>
                <input type="text" id="link" name="link"/>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label>Normal:</label>
            <input type="text" id="normal2" name="normal2"/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

li .ui-field-contain {
    margin-right: 42px; !important;
}
.readonly-btn-a {
    background:             #fff!important /*{a-bup-background-color}*/;
    color:                  #333!important /*{a-bup-color}*/;
    text-shadow: 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-x}*/ 1px /*{a-bup-shadow-y}*/ 0 /*{a-bup-shadow-radius}*/ #f3f3f3 /*{a-bup-shadow-color}*/;
    cursor: default !important;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

> Here is an updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/F5XFP/3/)** (based on Jeff's GOOD answer)

UPDATE: for less padding within the LI elements add:

```
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/F5XFP/4/)**

Comment: That's awesome, but the wide space between the "li"s does bother me a little. Is this because of .ui-body-inherit?

Comment: yes, here is an update with better spacing: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/F5XFP/4/, all i did was add .ui-listview>.ui-li-static { padding-top: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important;} (answer has been updated).

Comment: Thanks, it seems your answer also does what Jeff's solution failed to provide: constant space between text input and link. (although this wasn't even required until now so I can't blame him)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use jQuery mobile for the styling? Might be easier if you assigned data-role='none' to your input boxes and styled everything separately in your CSS. I've done this on projects just because trying to get jQuery mobile to behave can be a little difficult.

Comment: I don't think I have the skills to do this. I'd only go for that if it is the only possible way.

Comment: If you add a little padding, around 3px, to your `.readonly-btn-a` class you should be able to get the halo effect to work. The elements do not line up because you have 3 elements in one list item and 2 in the other. To get them to line up, maybe set the Link label to have an auto width and a right margin of 5%?

Comment: I figured out problem one myself by assigning all the passing to .readonly-btn-a instead of .readonly-li-a. But "width: auto" only widens the gap. I tried setting the margin to higher values, but everything above 16% simply makes the textbox go into the next line.

Comment: Ok this should work. Add the following classes to your CSS:
`.ui-field-contain>label+[class*=ui-] {
    width: 72% !important;
}

.ui-listview>li.ui-li-has-alt>.ui-btn {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}`
See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5XFP/

Comment: That really works, thanks. :) Is it possible to always have the same distance from text input to link on the right? Because the way it is now, it uses up a lot of free space on the right when the site enters the "split-in-2-lines" mode.

Comment: Add these classes:
`.ui-mobile label {
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
}
.ui-field-contain>label+[class*=ui-]{
width: 72% !important;
display: inline-block;
}`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5XFP/5/

The problem being now is that your CSS is very bloated. I understand if you don't feel confident yet in styling your elements yourself, but I highly suggest you at least try and sandbox a solution, even if it's not the solution you implement.

Comment: I just realized ezanker's answer already provided a solution for this. But thanks anyway.